# client is disconnecting from mosquitto broker and not connecting again to same broker

Tags: node.js, meteor, mqtt, messagebroker

I am running mosquitto broker on 'iot.eclipse.org'.After publishing some commands to broker from my app server,client is disonnecting and calling reconnect and close methods continuously,but not connecting again unless I restart my server.But I want it to reconnect again,once connection breaks.
My code is as follows:

```
var options = {
        host: 'iot.eclipse.org',
        port: 1883,

    };
    var client = mqtt.connect(options);
    client.on('connect', function (e) {
         console.log("client is connected");
         client.publish(topic, message,callback);
        });

    client.on("reconnect", function() {
            console.log("client is reconnected",JSON.stringify());
          })
    client.on("error", function(err) {
            console.log("error from client --> ", err);
          })
    client.on("close", function(e) {
             console.log("client is closed",JSON.stringify(options),JSON.stringify(e));
          })
    client.on("offline", function(err) {
            console.log("client is offline");
          });
    client.on('message', function (topic, message) {
            console.log('*********');
            console.log(message.toString());
        })
```

Comment: Any errors or console output that states why it closes allthough it tried to reconnect?

Comment: try out "broker.hivemq.com" instead "iot.eclipse.org". due to a lot of traffic on the broker, it sometimes happens

Comment: No,it is not showing any errors or console output@Jankapunkt

Comment: But it is publishing exactly 48 commands in sequence,after that calling reconnect and close sometimes offline method@karan sharma